# how to read whole excel file in asp.net using c#

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-3.0

how to read whole excel file in asp.net not single sheet in excel file.I want to read whole.For instance in excel file have 3 sheets i want to read 3 sheets at a time..plz any one can help me......

Answer (score 0):

Aspose has some pretty decent libs for .net to read and create office documents. I don't think it's for free though.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different ways to read the Excel file; however, it's not quite clear that why you want to read the whole Excel file. Do you just want to read the contents to a stream? Or you want to edit those contents?

[Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) allows you to read and work with Excel files. You can try to load the Excel file and then save to the same format but in Memory Stream, if you want to further process it in your code. However, you can also perform various operations after loading the Excel file. You may find the details in the [Aspose.Cells for .NET documentation](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/index.html).

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks 4 reply...actually whole file in the sense,in my excel file have 3 sheets i need to read 3 sheets at a time,i mean 3 sheets content only and need to display in grid view

Answer (score 0):

Marcos Meli's [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) is an open source alternative.  It can't do everything excel related, but it can read and write excel files.  You do have to have Excel installed on the machine though, IIRC.

I really don't understand what you mean by "read the whole file".  Excel is built on an object model that breaks things down into documents, sheets, cells, etc.. you can only really work with one sheet at a time.  Please explain what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For .xlsx files, you can also try OpenXML SDK

[Open XML Developer](http://www.openxmldeveloper.org/)

[Download OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not the best way to go, but it is an option if you *must* read all of the data 'at one time'.  You could write a function that appends each sheet's UsedRange to the UsedRange of the first sheet.  All of the data would then be in that first sheet, which you could easily read. This would not be fast, but it would be pretty simple to do using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#.  Just watch out for sheet size limits if you are working with large or a large number of sheets.

It may be the best option to re-think how you are doing this, as data from the second sheet is not on the first sheet for a reason.